# setAttributedText is not working on UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to set attributed string title on UIButton but its seems not working here.

```
[self.emailSignInButton.titleLabel setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL", nil) attributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}]];
```

While this completely works fine.

```
[self.emailSignInButton.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL", nil)];
```

The strange thing is another button text is fine with attributed text.
eg.

```
[self.emailSignupButton.titleLabel setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"CREATE_ACCOUNT_WITH_EMAIL", nil) attributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}]]`;
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the text for the state of the button. There are a few different states a UIButton can be in.

- Normal
- Highlighted
- Disabled
- Selected
- Focused
- Application
- Reserved

You will most likely need *Normal*, this will set a default title for all cases.

> **UIButton**
>
> - setAttributedTitle:forState:
>
> Sets the styled title to use for the specified state.

Here is an example with your code

```
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL", nil) 
                                                            attributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}]

[self.emailSignInButton setAttributedTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

references:

[UIControlState](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState)

[UIButton - setAttributedTitle:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setAttributedTitle:forState:)

Comment: It's now setting empty string to the UIButton title label.

Comment: @kidsid49 can you elaborate? Did you set the title for the state? Do you have some example code?

Comment: Yeah I did what you suggested setting for the state and then it happened.

Comment: I did this     NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL", nil) attributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];
    
    [self.emailSignInButton setAttributedTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.emailSignInButton setAttributedTitle:string forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];